# On Android 14 devices onBackPressed works with big delay

Tags: android, android-activity, back, onbackpressed, android-14

Few days ago I updated my phone to Android 14. I noticed that when I use onBackPressed to back from one Activity to another it takes about 6-7 seconds till it really happen. I know that right now `OnBackPressed` is depracated but I also tried with `getOnBackPressedDispatcher().onBackPressed();` and the results was same. I didn't noticed that problem when we are using onBackPressed to switch between fragments. One more case when I saw it was using for example Facebook app when I tried to close/minimize it using onBackPressed navigation gesture and it doesn't works from time to time.